# python, PyQt4 - get folder path in QTreeView with Enter Key

Tags: python, pyqt

I`m using this code to get folder(or file) path on QTreeView.

```
self.mytreeview.clicked.connect(self.mytreeview_clicked)
```

But I want to control all things with a keyboard, so I want to use EnterKey instead click. I did google but cannot find any solution or example. How should I do?

Here`s my code:

```
self.btn_myrootPath = QPushButton("Select Root Folder")
self.btn_myrootPath.clicked.connect(self.set_myrootPath)
self.myfsm = QFileSystemModel(self)
self.myfsm.setRootPath(self.myrootPath)
self.myfsm.setReadOnly(True)
self.myfsm.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)

self.myrootPath_l = QLabel()
self.myrootPath_l.setText(self.myrootPath)

self.mytreeview = QTreeView(self)
self.mytreeview.setModel(self.myfsm)
self.mytreeview.setRootIndex(self.myfsm.index(self.myfsm.rootPath()))
self.mytreeview.clicked.connect(self.mytreeview_clicked)
self.mytreeview.setColumnHidden(1, True)
self.mytreeview.setColumnHidden(2, True)
self.mytreeview.setColumnWidth(0, 800)
```

And this is mytreeview_clicked function:

```
def mytreeview_clicked(self, index):
    indexItem = self.myfsm.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
    path = str(self.myfsm.filePath(indexItem))
    ......
```

-----------------EDIT--------------------

I found the answer.
just change

```
self.mytreeview.clicked.connect(self.mytreeview_clicked)
```

into

```
self.mytreeview.activated.connect(self.mytreeview_clicked)
```

This code calls function `self.mytreeview_clicked` when double clicked or press EnterKey.

Answer (score 0):

You can reate a custom signal instead of the clicked event.

```python
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget): #Your classname
    keyPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super(MyWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        self.keyPressed.emit()
...
```

So that you can use

```
self.mytreeview.keyPressed.connect(self.mytreeview_clicked)
```

instead of

```
self.mytreeview.clicked.connect(self.mytreeview_clicked)
```

Alternativly you can handle each keyPressEvent with a different Signal and handle its emit.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('MYSIGNAL'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I followed your answer but it didn't work. The message was " AttributeError: 'QTreeView' object has no attribute 'keyPressed' "

Comment: Okay, let's try it this way:
If you want QTreeView to handle the keyEvent we need to overwrite the keyPressEvent on that widget instead of the MainWindow. If you want the mainWindow to handle all events go for the second approach. If you dont want to use the signals you can try to call the function from there, tho the GUI will freeze during this process